# Why didn't Berlin clean it up?

Tags: plot-explanation, berlin

In the last episode of [*Berlin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_(Spanish_TV_series)) (2023) (*Money Heist* prequel spinoff) we see that

> Camille walks to the Berlins hotel room and all the heist equipment is there.

But why?

> Berlin already waited for Damián in the coffe downstairs and they agreed to leave.

Berlin had a lot of time to clean up before that (afterall the original plan was to not be there at all).